# SharePoint 2010 Modified By UserName Changed to Created By UserName All List Items

Tags: sharepoint-foundation

We noticed on all our SharePoint lists that all the `"modified by"` got changed to the creator of the list item for every list item (regardless of the date).

I tried editing an existing item and after I saved the list item the modified by username updated to my username correctly.  New items that are created from users are doing the same thing.

Anyone have tips on how to troubleshoot this?

I tried researching it and verified the XML schema is correct. ([Modified By Column does not get updated](http://blogs.technet.com/b/victorbutuza/archive/2015/08/04/modified-by-column-does-not-get-updated.aspx))

The only change I have done recently is updating an item field without having the modified by field change from the blog [Update item or document properties without changing the Modified or Modified By fields using SharePoint Powershell](http://www.sharepointsapiens.com/blog/update-item-document-properties-without-changing-modified-modified-fields-using-sharepoint-powershell/).